# Get the latest record added to an audit table and send email

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sharepoint, reporting-services

I am trying to get the latest record which is added to an audit table and send an email to some people in my organisation with the details of the record added but not sure how to do this.

I am using Sharepoint SSRS report to show the data using the following query -

```
-- for records which have updated BUSTYPE
SELECT UPPER(caa.Comments) + ' Record' 'SQLAction'
    , c.BUS_TYPE AS CurrentBusType
    , caa.BUS_TYPE AS PrevBusType
    , caa.LastModified
    , c.CUSTOMERID
    , c.NAME
    , c.ADDRESS1
    , c.ADDRESS2
    , c.CITY
    , c.STATE
    , c.ZIP, 
FROM CUSTOMER_Audit AS caa
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS c ON caa.CUSTOMERID = c.CUSTOMERID 
where ISNULL(caa.BUS_TYPE,'') != ISNULL(c.BUS_TYPE,'')
AND (ISNULL(caa.BUS_TYPE,'') = '' OR ISNULL(c.BUS_TYPE,'') = '')
AND ISNULL(c.BUS_TYPE,'') = ''
AND DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(date, caa.LastModified), GETDATE()) <= 30 -- last 30 days filter

UNION

-- for records which are deleted
SELECT UPPER(caa.Comments) + ' Record' 'SQLAction'
    ,'' AS CurrentBusType
    , caa.BUS_TYPE AS PrevBusType
    , caa.LastModified
    , caa.CUSTOMERID
    , caa.NAME
    , caa.ADDRESS1
    , caa.ADDRESS2
    , caa.CITY
    , caa.STATE
    , caa.ZIP 
FROM CUSTOMER_Audit AS caa
WHERE caa.Comments LIKE '%Deleted%'
AND DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(date, caa.LastModified), GETDATE()) <= 30
ORDER BY caa.LastModified DESC
```

How can I send email for only the last records which are added after the previous email was sent with some records.

The new email should not send the updated/deleted records which have already been sent in the previous email.

I tried using snapshot in Sharepoint but it is sending all the snapshots with the same records which have already been sent (along with the new records if there are any). Don't know if I am doing something wrong there.

Or, should I adjust my SQL query to only show the latest records? But how can I do that?

My SQL Server is 2008 R2.

Comment: You typically need to flag/track records which you have already notified about, or store the if of the last record processed.

Comment: @DaleK I dont want to add a new column (for flag) just for this report

Comment: You need someway to identify which records you have already notified for.

Comment: true but thats what I am trying to figure out - any ideas except for adding a new column (flag)

Comment: Yes, I gave you another idea, store the maximum id you send each time, and then filter higher than that. There is no magic way to know which records you have processed(notified), you need to build some mechanism.

Comment: And as an aside, your version of SQL Server is dangerously out of date. You need to plan to upgrade ASAP.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK thats seems to be a very good idea but where should I store the maxID of CustomerAudit table? in SQL or in SSRS report builder? Sorry cant figure out still as I am very new to all this

Comment: Also I would use `UNION ALL` unless you are using `UNION` to remove duplicates (which makes it run quite a lot slower).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution is to create a table which records the last record displayed on a report e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ReportHistory (
    -- Following is a way to identify the report, could be plain text
    -- Could be the ID of the report in SSRS
  Report varchar(128)
  , LastIdQueried bigint
)
```

Then each time you run the report you update this table. And is assuming you pull your results via a stored procedure.

However this is problematic in that if you run the report manually from SSRS, without emailing the results out, you'll not be notified about them.

Therefore what I tend to do in a situation like this is create my own snapshot, triggered off an agent job at a time of my choosing, and then display the data from this static snapshot. My schema for this snapshot (simplified) is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ReportInstance (
    Id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    DateOfReportRun datetime2(0) NULL,
    -- Following is a way to identify the report, could be plain text
    -- Could be the ID of the report in SSRS
    Report varchar(128) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ReportInstanceItem (
    Id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    ReportInstance bigint NULL REFERENCES dbo.ReportInstance(Id),
    -- Store the ids from the target table which are part of this report
    RecordId bigint NULL
);
```

Comment: Your solutions seems very very impressive. Just few more questions on it. How can I insert data in reportHistory from a stored proc when stored proc is on a different server db than a report server db? In the second solution did you mean I have to create a sql agent job on my actual db server and insert values in ReportInstance and ReportInstanceItem?

Comment: 1) However you choose to store data, you store it in your actual database - not your SSRS database. 2) Correct you are building your own snapshot of the report, again in your own database not SSRS.